# How do I use an R matrix of type "list"?

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have an R object of the form

```r
obj <- structure(list(3), dim = c(1L, 1L), dimnames = list("a", "b"))
```

I wish to perform basic arithmetic on this structure, but when I perform, say, `obj / 3`, I see `Error in obj/3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator` – reflecting, I suppose, that one can't treat a `list` as an object.

What surprised me is that `as.matrix(obj)` returns the original object – not, as I'd expect, `structure(c(3), dim = c(1L, 1L), dimnames = list("a", "b"))`.  I suppose that this is because `as.matrix(obj)` is true.

I'm intrigued by the existence of a matrix that is internally represented as a list.  What are the advantages / use cases of such a representation?  And is there a simple way to convert such an object to a numeric mode?  I can only think of the cumbersome

```r
matrix(unlist(obj), nrow(obj), ncol(obj), dimnames = dimnames(obj))
```

### How I came to have the structure

I have a function that takes two vectors and m-applies a function to them – for simplicity I've just used `+` here.

```r
a <- c(a = 1)
b <- c(b = 2)

mat <- matrix(.mapply("+", list(rep(b, each = length(a)), a), NULL),
              nrow = length(a), ncol = length(b),
              dimnames = list(names(a), names(b))
)

dput(mat)
mat / 1 # Error
```

Placing `unlist()` around the call to `.mapply` would generate a conventional matrix.

Comment: It is not obvious what are you really doing and trying to achieve. Maybe look function `outer`.

Comment: The advantage of a list matrix is that you can use matrix subsetting. That's it. If you expect to be able to do arithmetics with a data structure, a list is the wrong data type / storage mode (because a list can contain anything, not just numeric data).